# Search event point in time-based data using Python

Tags: python, numpy, search, time

I have a numpy.datatime64 array (several hundred thousand times with non-constant time step) and a table with 100-200 time values (e.g. 2018-08-12 09:00:00). I need to use the values in this table and find the nearest time in a numpy array (let's say I want the position of that time point in the array). Does anyone know a time-saving way to make such search in time-based data using Python?
I solved this problem by converting the whole time to OLE2 format and searching the nearest numbers in the array through a loop, but it takes several tens of seconds.

Comment: are the samples sorted? did you try binary search?

Comment: Yes - big numpy array is a time series with logical time consequence, time table also has a growing trend. The problem is that time events from the table can be different from time values in array for several seconds or minutes (i.e. can be between two time points). I solved this problem as described above, but I'm looking for a more effective algorithm (if exists).

Comment: Your description seems a bit convoluted to me.
It would help if you a small part of your code in a self-contained frame and a small sample of your data as well as a **minimal** reproducible example with an input and it's expected output